# Should i trust php variable $_SERVER[AUTH_USER] when signing in via Windows Authentication? IIS intranet hosted app

Tags: php, iis, active-directory, iis-7.5, ntlm

I've hosted (on IIS 7.5) basic php website, which simply returns me $*SERVER variable contents. I have notcied that there are AUTH** array fields:

```
["AUTH_USER"]=>
string(18) "MYDOMAIN\my_username"
["AUTH_PASSWORD"]=>
string(0) ""
["AUTH_TYPE"]=>
string(9) "Negotiate"
// .... some more variables
 ["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"]=>
string(174) "Negotiate (token_here)"
```

Why AUTH_PASSWORD is empty?
Also, should i trust this variable? Can i safely assume that user "my_username" has successfully been logged ?
Also should i do anything with "HTTP_AUTHORIZATION" token ? Should i verify it?

I'll appreciate any help.

EDIT:
Someone asked about code, there is no code, only this:

```
var_dump($_SERVER);
```

Comment: This obviously depends on the code which you did not post! how should we answer without that?

Comment: There is only "var_dump($_SERVER)". IIS server handles whole authentication process.

Comment: No, IIS certainly does _not_ handle the authentication process. At least not somehow automagically. Either you have PHP code that authenticates against whatever authority or you don't. If you do _not_ have such code, then there is no authentication done.

Comment: Are you sure about that ? Im using windows authentication and internet explorer - and i've read that IIS and IE handles authentication there.

Comment: It could also be that you are referring to http basic authentication. But there certainly is not some magic going on in background.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should, this is called [Integrated Windows Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Windows_Authentication).

The reason `AUTH_PASSWORD` is empty is because you don't need to know the password; you only need to know that the user has successfully logged into Windows using the `AUTH_USER`